# How to convert strings to floats after sending through TCP with Python?

Tags: python, string, sockets, tcp

Hi am trying to send continuous temperature data from my Raspberry Pi 3 to PC using TCP sockets with Python. I'm not unable to send float values, I am sending a continuous stream of float values in string format and want to convert all of these to float types.

I am getting errors like this:

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float '25.69'.
```

Here is my server code (running on the raspberry pi), I've only included the specific parts:

```
def dataTransfer(conn):
    # A big loop that sends/receives data until told not to.
    while True:
    reply = GET_OBJ_TEMP()
    reply = str(reply)
    #conn.sendall(str.encode(reply)) # don't have to encode/decode, I think it's only for Python 3
    conn.sendall(reply)
    print("Data has been sent!")
    #conn.close()

s = setupServer()
conn = setupConnection()
dataTransfer(conn)
```

And here is the client code (on PC):

```
import socket

host = '10.0.0.94'
port = 5560

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

#while True:
#s.send(str.encode(command))
reply = s.recv(1024)
#print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
#reply2 = reply.decode('utf-8')
reply2 = (repr(reply))
reply2 = float(reply2)
print reply2
print type(reply2)

s.close()
```

Could someone please help me to get these values as an float or help me send floats directly, i need them so i can use temperature as a threshold value.

Comment: Just remove this `reply2 = (repr(reply))`, it adds quotes to your data

Comment: It worked, thank you!!

Comment: Though now, I am trying to get it to work for a continuous stream of temp readings, using a while loop it doesn't like it, it gets a very big float number.. how would i fix this?

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 27.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8
527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8
527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8527.8
5

Comment: TCP is a stream oriented protocol, you may get one, several or even part of a float in each read on server. Some options are, use UDP and send one float per datagram (this is simple but  inneficient in terms of bandwidth usage) or separate float values with some special character like new line and use that on server to split different values.

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure how to do this, I managed to get a work around by changing reducing the bytes received s.recv from 1024 to 50.. and then slicing the string to 4 characters using reply2 = reply2[:5], I can then convert them all to floats.